# R create strings in a loop

Tags: r, variables, loops, for-loop, string-concatenation

How can I create variables and strings using the value passed by the loop?

---

**Example**

I have a set of countries = c('USA','Canada','Mexico').

I have a dataframe 'population'.

I want to query my database to get their population, and assign it to a column in a data frame. Don't worry about accessing the database, I am only concerned with dynamically creating the query string and the dataframe column name.

```
for (country in countries) {
   query = "SELECT population FROM population_database WHERE location='country';"
   population$country = mysql_query(query) 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for the `paste` function.

```
x <- "USA"
paste("location =", x)
#[1] "location = USA"
```

Comment: Unfortunately paste() seems to be inserting a space when I use it to name a variable.

Comment: regions = 'USA'
variable = paste('rev.', region)

Comment: `paste('rev', region, sep='.')` or `paste('rev.', region, sep='')`, or `paste0('rev.', region)`

Comment: Yes - inserting a space is the default.  As GSee points out you can change the separating character/string.  Read `?paste`

Comment: When I use paste for the variable I get:  `target of assignment expands to non-language object`

Comment: You didn't actually tell us how you were using paste so it's hard to diagnose why you got that message.  Have you read the help page for past yet (`?paste`)?  There are examples that show you how to use it.  You should construct your query using paste and then pass that into mysql_query.

Answer (score 2):

Now, if you would like to create a for loop and then create new string names you can do this

```
a=c()
for (i in 1:5) {
    d=paste("location = ", i)
    a=c(a,d)
}
```

Hence,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want `population[[country]]` rather than `population$country`.  The `$` notation is a shortcut for `[[` and "the longest distance between 2 points is a shortcut."

Others already mentioned `paste` and `past0`, you could also use `sprintf` or the `gsubfn` package.